# Populating DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Following code is to create users. I have a user class, I need to create users here. But I have department id's on a person and that department id refers to another table in the database whose name is Department.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // disable lazy because of error it creates
    _db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    var data = _db.Departments.OrderBy(a => a.DepartmentId).ToList();
    ViewData["DepartmentList"] = data;

    return View();
}
```

Here is View:

```
@{
    var departmentLists = ViewData["DepartmentList"]; // Cast the list
}

<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

This model.department part is the where i lost. I need to list my department in order of the list, when user select, i want to select the id of the department.
Like this;

[image]

So I want the user to see

> Department Name + SubDepartment name

and when they choose from the list, the chosen thing is

> departmentid

so I can add in the database like that.

Here is my Create Post method:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate,Email,Department,Position,Active")] User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Users.Add(user);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

     return View(user);
 }
```

Her is my User class;

```
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    // Other fields removed for brevity
}
```

Here is `Department` class;

```
public class Department
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public string SubDepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is that `Department` property has `enum` type in viewmodel class? If you want to display concatenated text value, I think you should try `DropDownListFor` instead.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I am not sure what to choose to display, that is why I ask this question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your `Create` GET method as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // disable lazy because of error it creates
    _db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var departmentList = _db.Departments.Select(d => new
     {
        d.DepartmentId,
        DepartmentName = d.DepartmentName + " " + d.SubDepartmentName
     }).OrderBy(a => a.DepartmentId).ToList();

    ViewBag.DepartmentList = new SelectList(departmentList,"DepartmentId","DepartmentName");

    return View();
}
```

Then in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", ViewBag.DepartmentList as SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Another problem is in your `Create` `POST` method. You are not allowing you `DepartmentId` to pass in your `Bind` include list. Please update you `Create` `POST` method as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate,Email,DepartmentId,Position,Active")] User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       _db.Users.Add(user);
       _db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Almost true, just it is not posting the department id that we choose into database.

Comment: Please explain the problem somewhat further. I shall fix!

Comment: Edited your answer as a working version and added user class at my question. All is fine except database did not receive 1 value as a departmentid when I create the user and post the value.

Comment: No, sorry, misunderstanding happen. Still posting the departmentid is not working. Rest is okey.

Comment: Can you give me remote access please!

Comment: I strongly disagree with your `DropDownList` usage, use the strongly-typed helper version instead.

Comment: When i choose from dropdown the item 1, it must post departmentid to 1 value. If I choose item 2, it must post departmentid to value 2, etc etc.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto You have no idea about `SelectList`. Don't Mind please! We are sharing knowledge here. Select-list behind the scene implements `SelectListItem`. Would be grateful if you remove the downvote please! thank you.

Comment: @Thatshowweroll Would you please add your Department Model class in the question please!

Comment: @TanvirArjel i did

Comment: got the problem! I am updating my answer!

Comment: When you said, I found and your answer also correct. Thank you

Comment: Great to see your problem has been fixed! Welcome!